# grunt.util.spawn NOT working on Windows

Tags: gruntjs

```
var child = grunt.util.spawn({
   cmd: 'echo %PATH%'
}, function(error, result, code) {
   cb(error, result.stdout);
});
```

When I executed 'echo %PATH%' in my windows command prompt, it works fine.
But grunt.util.spawn is producing error like this:

> >>Error: Error: not found: echo %PATH%

Tried googling over an hour, but no luck. Please help me.

Comment: Nothing? Anybody help me!

Comment: I'm having the same problem but on Mac. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @mags The reason I came up with this issue is that it didn't get executed properly and errored out when I tried to run a self-executable php script. It was actually written something like this: `cmd: path.join(__dirname, '../bin/jadephp')`, here jadephp is a self-executable php script (which starts with a line `#!/usr/bin/env php`), but it didn't work. So instead of executing it directly, I came up with this solution; `cmd: 'php', args: path.join(__dirname, '../bin/jadephp')`. What are you going to do with executing `echo %PATH%` in your case?

Comment: Actually my problem was a little different. I was trying to run selenium standalone-server via grunt.util.spawn so that the users of my script would not have to separately start the server. However, I kept getting a "0 passing, 0 done" message in the terminal without the server actually starting. Then when I tried to run basic commands like "npm install" through grunt.util.spawn I was getting "command not found". I'm thinking maybe I have too little understanding of how grunt.util.spawn works?? For now I've kind of given up :(

Comment: @mags why don't you post a new question about your issue on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need "%PATH%" to be passed as an argument like this:

```js
var child = grunt.util.spawn({
   cmd: 'echo', 
  args: ['%PATH%'],
}, function(error, result, code) {
   cb(error, result.stdout);
});
```